# SSL connection code fails with error code ENOTFOUND on bluemix, but code works perfectly on localhost

Tags: node.js, ssl, ibm-cloud

I have an application that makes an outbound HTTPS request to an internal server to fetch some data and then sends that data back to the client.  When I run the code on my local machine, it works perfectly as expected.  However, when I push the code to bluemix, I get error ENOTFOUND.

Here is the code:

```
var options = {
    host: 'servername',
    path: "path",
    port: '7988',
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('mycertificate.crt'),
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

var GIS_req = https.get(options, function(GIS_res) {

    GIS_res.on('data', function(d) {
        res.send("" + d);
    });
    GIS_res.on('error', function(e) {
        res.send("" + e);
    });
});

GIS_req.on('error', function(e) {
    res.send("GIS req error " + e);
});
```

Edit: The code works fine on both the server and my local machine for HTTP requests, just not for HTTPS.

Comment: can you please run `cf logs <app name>` --recent and post here?

Comment: 2016-02-05T13:21:46.08-0500 [App/0]      ERR GIS req error Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <servername>
2016-02-05T13:21:46.08-0500 [RTR/1]      OUT <app url> - [05/02/2016:18:21:46 +0000] "GET /4519003131305021 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36" 10.115.2.136:30887 x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:7a6388ea-1184-4f6e-443f-9ddeabda8330 response_time:0.02299195 app_id:b4bcac0e-03e3-4c39-b342-b31597019f3b x_global_transaction_id:"57577581"

Comment: Per the error above your application cannot access your server. Please note that Bluemix application run in the public Internet, so if the server you are trying to access is behind a firewall the app will not be able to reach it.

Comment: I neglected to mention that accessing the server via HTTP instead of HTTPS works fine, even on bluemix.